# Run PHP script in the background

Tags: php, database, video, background, save

I have a popup that runs and it saves my video. Another window opens letting me know the window has been saved, but it's pretty ugly. Is there any way to run it in the background and open a javascript popup or potentially a fixed position div that I can get rid of?

Nothing I have tried has worked. I'm not really sure where to go. Here is my on click code:

```
onclick="var my_window = window.open('/saving.php?token=<?=$token?>', 'mywindow1',       'width=300,height=200,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=0,    top=0');"
```

Can I run /saving.php in the background and give a different notification?

Comment: Did you considered using ajax to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about Ajax, so you'd visit this page "running" it and wait for the reply to come back and use that to trigger your alert.

Ajax 101: http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

Simple example (with jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().load("saving.php", function(data){
        alert("Finished running")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the video via the jQuery [Form-plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

You then can define a success-handler to show your notification-DIV (or whatever else). However the user will have to stay on the page for the duration of the video-upload.